# Querys en relaciones NaN con Sequelize

Tags: nodejs, sequelize.js

estoy desarrollando una API con Node.js en conjunto con Sequelize y no se como realizar una query.
Hay un modelo Pelicula y otro Personaje, los personajes pertenecen a varias peliculas y las peliculas tienen varios personajes.
Me piden que filtre los personajes por una determinada pelicula.¿Saben como podria realizar esa query?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué código tienes?

Answer (score 0):

encontre la solucion. Seria algo como :

```
Character.findAll({
    where: {
        "$Movies.title$": req.query.movie
    }, 
    include: {
        model: Movie, as: Movie.tableName,
        attributes: ["title"]
    }  
})
```